# Sharepoint Designer on Office365 Websites

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, sharepoint-designer

I have a Office365 PRO account subscription, which offers integrated sharepoint websites, and I want to use the Sharepoint Designer for designing Forms in my Websites.

Now, in the designer, I can open the site and ASPX pages, but I can only edit the HTML Code. I don't see the graphical designer area, and all toolbar items like Button, Textbox, etc. are disabled.

The program also says "the page does not contain any regions that are editable in safe mode": 
[image]

So, how can I create a sharepoint website which can be fully edited with the Sharepoint Designer ?

I have of course downloaded the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design View was removed from SharePoint 2013:

https://blogs.office.com/2012/10/10/changes-to-the-design-view-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/

The alternative would be mapping your SharePoint site as a network drive unit and work with your favorite WYSIWYG editor, but that would have many limitations.